# Asp.net Mvc 5, two account controller and Area but redirect to wrong login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, authorization

I have and Area in my mvc 5 project.
In area, I've copied Controllers from root of my project and AccountController too.

I have a create form and controller for NewsController which has [Authorize] attribute at beginning of the class.

But when not logged in and want to create a news, form posted back to login of root my project, not Area part.

These are my controller and views part:

project structure:

- Areas

  - Admin

    - Controllers
    - AboutsController.cs
    - NewsController.cs
    - Views
    - Create.cshtml

Create.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "News", FormMethod.Post,
                                    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 ....
```

NewsController.cs :

```
 namespace Project.Areas.Admin.Controllers
    {
        [Authorize]
        public class NewsController : Controller
        {
             ...
        }

          public ActionResult Create()
                {            
                        return View();            
                }
     }
```

And AccountController.cs is the same in root controller folder.

Remember: I've added

**new {area="Admin"}**

to form but,
redirect goes to login login page of root again, instead of Areas/Admin/login

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "News", FormMethod.Post,new {area="Admin"},
                                    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting redirected to default login route. If you want to change the default login route, it is configured inside the App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs file.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
    // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
    // Configure the sign in cookie
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
```

Change the *LoginPath* value to your desired value.

**To change the login page for specific Area:**
you need to create the custom authorization attribute, like:

```
public class AdminAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // If you are authorized
        if (this.AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            // else redirect to your Area  specific login page
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Area/Admin/Account/Login");
        }
    }
}
```

and apply it to your area controller, as:

```
[AdminAuthorize]
public class NewsController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well, I have two authentication controllers. This one you've mentioned is for root of site, and I need this too. If I change PathString("/Account/Login") to PathString("/Area/Admin/Account/Login") , I will lost my login of root. Have any Idea?

Comment: I have edited answer for your scenario. I hope it'll help.